# how to order a parameter by power?

Tags: formatting, order

for example, y=a x^2+ a(b x^2)+c^3 x^2+z^2+c z
how to tansfer function y to formart like y=?x^2+ ?x+? and y=?z^2+?z+?
So, I want to tansfer the equation below to arrange both A_{2l} and A_{2h} (one answer is ascending the order of A_{2l} while another answer is ascending order A_{2h})in ascending order. Thank you so much. 
[image]

```
(-4 (Subscript[c, n] + Subscript[c, nature] - Subscript[\[Delta], 
m]) + k (-2 Subscript[A, 2 l] (-1 + Subscript[c, l]) + 
Subscript[A, 
2 h] (2 - 
Subscript[c, 
h] (2 + (2 + k Subscript[A, 2 l]) Subscript[\[Lambda], h]) + 
Subscript[\[Lambda], 
h] (-2 + 4 Subscript[c, n] + 4 Subscript[c, nature] + 
2 k Subscript[A, 2 h] (-1 + Subscript[\[Lambda], h]) + 
2 Subscript[\[Delta], m] (-1 + Subscript[\[Lambda], h]) + 
k Subscript[A, 
2 l] (-2 + Subscript[c, 
l] + (1 - Subscript[c, l] + Subscript[c, n] + Subscript[
c, nature]) Subscript[\[Lambda], h]))) + 
Subscript[A, 
2 l] (-2 (1 + k Subscript[A, 2 l] + Subscript[c, l] - 
2 Subscript[c, n] - 2 Subscript[c, nature] + 
Subscript[\[Delta], m]) + 
k Subscript[A, 
2 h] (-2 + Subscript[c, h] - Subscript[c, 
l] + (Subscript[c, h] + Subscript[c, l] - 
2 (-1 + Subscript[c, n] + Subscript[c, 
nature])) Subscript[\[Lambda], 
h])) Subscript[\[Lambda], l] + 
Subscript[A, 
2 l] (k Subscript[A, 
2 h] (1 - Subscript[c, h] + Subscript[c, n] + Subscript[c, 
nature]) + 
2 (k Subscript[A, 2 l] + Subscript[\[Delta], m])) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(l\), \(2\)]\) - 
2 Subscript[A, 
2] (2 + k Subscript[A, 
2 h] (-1 + Subscript[\[Lambda], h]) Subscript[\[Lambda], h] +
k Subscript[A, 
2 l] (-1 + Subscript[\[Lambda], l]) Subscript[\[Lambda], 
l])))
```

Comment: If you are typing these by hand, you can use HoldForm. For example HoldForm[y^2 + x^2]. If it is an output from a computation you will likely have to select the elements, convert them to strings, join them together etc..any reason why you want it to be so ?

Comment: because I want to analysis the relationship between y and A_{2l} , also the relationship between y and A_{2h}

Answer (score 2):

Use indexed variables. Subscripts cannot be variables.

```
Format[c[n_]] := Subscript[c, n];
Format[δ[n_]] := Subscript[δ, n];
Format[A[n_]] := Subscript[A, n];
Format[λ[n_]] := Subscript[λ, n];

expr = -4 (c[n] + c[nature] - δ[m]) + 
   k (-2 A[2 l] (-1 + c[l]) + 
      A[2 h] (2 - 
         c[h] (2 + (2 + k A[2 l]) λ[h]) + λ[
           h] (-2 + 4 c[n] + 4 c[nature] + 
            2 k A[2 h] (-1 + λ[h]) + 
            2 δ[m] (-1 + λ[h]) + 
            k A[2 l] (-2 + 
               c[l] + (1 - c[l] + c[n] + c[nature]) λ[h]))) + 
      A[2 l] (-2 (1 + k A[2 l] + c[l] - 2 c[n] - 
            2 c[nature] + δ[m]) + 
         k A[2 h] (-2 + c[h] - 
            c[l] + (c[h] + c[l] - 
               2 (-1 + c[n] + c[nature])) λ[h])) λ[
        l] + A[2 l] (k A[2 h] (1 - c[h] + c[n] + c[nature]) + 
         2 (k A[2 l] + δ[m])) λ[l]^2 - 
      2 A[2] (2 + k A[2 h] (-1 + λ[h]) λ[h] + 
         k A[2 l] (-1 + λ[l]) λ[l]));
```

Then use [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html)

```
(expr21 = Collect[expr, A[2 l]])
```

[image]

```
(expr22 = Collect[expr, A[2 h]])
```

[image]